# dimension mismatch error using Spark / MLLib Kmeans

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an input file of the following format:

```
1, 4, 5, 0, 3
0, 4, 5, 1, 4
.....
```

I loaded the file and trained Means and now want to use the predict function given in the `KMeansModel`, but I'm getting a dimension mismatch error and I'm not sure how to go about debugging. There doesn't seem to be any documentation on the input of the predict function.

code...

```
data = sc.textFile(join(movieLensHomeDir, "test.txt"))
ratings = data.map(lambda line: [float(x.rstrip().lstrip().split('\r\n')[0]) for x in line.split(",")])
model = KMeans.train(ratings, 15, maxIterations=15, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
labels = model.predict([0, 5, 3, 2, 4])
```

Comment: Map the RDD first (calculate the length) I'm sure that one record probably the last one has missing or additional values

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add "array" to your model.predict command?
e.g.

```
labels = model.predict((array([0, 5, 3, 2, 4]))
```

documentation for KMeans can be found here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel

Comment: Thanks Yaron. 
So I wanted to get the items that are clustered together. For example, I apply KMeans to cluster similar items. Then, I want to recommend items by providing a new item, finding the appropriate cluster and then suggesting items within that cluster. ... is there a way to determine what items are clustered together? There is noting in the docs about that.